# Add current product to the current logged in user meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, user-data

In WooCommerce product page, I'm trying to add the current product as a new user meta data. Am I doing this right?

Then how can I retrieve this product meta data in cart page?

```
// save for later
public function save_for_later(){
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) { 
        global $woocommerce;
        // get user details
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );;

        if (is_user_logged_in())
        {
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;
            $meta_key = 'product';
            $meta_value = $product;
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
        }
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the complete `WC_Product` Object, Which is a complex huge and heavy peace of data **that can not be saved as meta data**, you should **just better save the product ID**.

Why? Because the product ID is just an integer (so something very light) and will allow you to get the `WC_Product` Object **easily** from the saved product ID.

Now `global $woocommerce` is unneeded and `if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {` is not really required *(If it's needed you set add it back in the function)*.

Also `get_currentuserinfo();` is deprecated, unneeded too and replaced by `wp_get_current_user()`.

You should better need to be sure **that the current post ID is a "product" post type**. So try the following code instead:

```
// save for later
public function save_for_later(){
    global $post;

    // Check that the current post ID is a product ID and that current user is logged in
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_a($post, 'WP_Post') && get_post_type() === 'product' ) {
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'product_id', get_the_id());
    }
    exit();
}
```

Now **to retrieve this custom user meta data** and the WC_Product Object *(from the product ID)*, you will use:

```
$product_id = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'product_id', true );

// Get an instance of the WC_Product object from the product ID
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
```

In cart page, you might just need the product ID, depending on what you are trying to do. Everything should work.